# Unable to insert link to shared drive in sharepoint site

Tags: hyperlink

I am trying to link a document on one of the shared drives to a sharepoint site.
I inserted text in my webpart and went to links and tried to link the shared document. I was able to do this till yesterday. However I am not able to do it now. I did not change any setting on the webpart or the page. I get the below error message.

> cannot redirect to invalid url Missing or invalid protocol

I tried using the url which worked the other day, it still gave the same error message. Please help.

I used the following url to link the documents.

```
file:///G:\test\test.xlsx
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the FQDN of the NFS Drive.

Example:

```
\\tigerlan-fs01.your.domain.com\admin\
```

Not sure why downvoted but thanks for the help with the format.